Disambiguate table with name `object` in Jooq CodeGen
I am moving from Jooq 3.14.16 to Jooq 3.19.10
I am using codegen tool to generate Java source for jooq entities.
In the Postgres DB schema there are several tables and one of them is named object.
After moving to Jooq 3.19.10, generated entities fail to compile with error "method does not override or implement a method from a supertype".
15:08:09,464 [ERROR] /Users/shyama/projects/jooqtest/src/main/java/com/jooqtest/db/test/tables/Account.java:[331,5] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Steps to reproduce:
Create atleast 2 tables, one of them with name object, as;
CREATE TABLE jooqtest.account (
  id INT,
  details VARCHAR(32)
);

CREATE TABLE jooqtest.object (
  obj_id INT,
  details VARCHAR(32)
);

jooqtest.xml for cogegen input,
<configuration>
  <jdbc>
    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/supe</url>
    <user>supe</user>
    <password>xxxx</password>
  </jdbc>
  <generator>
    <database>
      <name>org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
      <includes>.*</includes>
      <excludes></excludes>
      <inputSchema>jooqtest</inputSchema>
    </database>
    <target>
      <packageName>org.jooqtest</packageName>
      <directory>entities</directory>
    </target>
  </generator>
</configuration>

Using jdk21 and running codegen in my Mac like below,
java -cp jOOQ-3.19.10/jOOQ-lib/r2dbc-spi-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:jOOQ-3.19.10/jOOQ-lib/reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar:jOOQ-3.19.10/jOOQ-lib/jakarta.xml.bind-api-3.0.0.jar:jOOQ-3.19.10/jOOQ-lib/jooq-3.19.10.jar:jOOQ-3.19.10/jOOQ-lib/jooq-codegen-3.19.10.jar:jOOQ-3.19.10/jOOQ-lib/jooq-meta-3.19.10.jar:postgresql-42.7.3.jar:. org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool jooqtest.xml

After jooq entity files are created,
In tables/Account.java method override looks like below,
    /**
     * Create an inline derived table from this table
     */
    @Override
    @PlainSQL
    public Account where(@Stringly.SQL String condition, Object... binds) {
        return where(DSL.condition(condition, binds));
    }

Whereas, in tables/Object.java it looks like,
    /**
     * Create an inline derived table from this table
     */
    @Override
    @PlainSQL
    public Object where(@Stringly.SQL String condition, java.lang.Object... binds) {
        return where(DSL.condition(condition, binds));
    }

Here the Object in Account class is not able to resolve to java.lang.Object
Hence compiler throws error.
Kindly suggest if there is any way to resolve it without renaming tables in DB?
I have provided Steps to Reproduce above.
I am expecting to resolve compiler error via some settings in codegen, without renaming tables in my existing DB.
Adding details of the runtime:
Following is the maven project's, root pom.xml content:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>testparentproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.develop-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Parent Project for test</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <!-- JDK -->
        <jdk.source.version>21</jdk.source.version>
        <jdk.target.version>21</jdk.target.version>
        <!-- Libraries -->
        <jooq.version>3.19.10</jooq.version>
        <!-- plugin versions -->
        <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.13.0</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
        <maven.resources.plugin.version>3.3.1</maven.resources.plugin.version>
        <maven.jar.plugin.version>3.4.2</maven.jar.plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <modules>
        <module>testjooq</module>
    </modules>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${jdk.source.version}</source>
                        <target>${jdk.target.version}</target>
                        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                        <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.resources.plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <propertiesEncoding>UTF-8</propertiesEncoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.jar.plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
                <version>${jooq.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>

Content of project testjooq/pom.xml is:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>testparentproject</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.develop-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>testjooq</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Jooq generated DB entities test</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>

Folder structure after placing jooq generated code looks like below,

Maven build command is mvn clean package.
Refer generated code in this repo: https://github.com/spsheni/jooqtest

"Hence compiler throws error." - I'm very curious about the specific compiler error (including your Java distribution and version), as there seems nothing wrong with this generated code, and I cannot reproduce the problem.

The actual compiler error message would be a helpful part of the problem description.

Compiler error message from mvn build,
15:08:09,464 [ERROR] /Users/shyama/projects/jooqtest/src/main/java/com/jooqtest/db/test/tables/Account.java:[331,5] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Here, tables folder contains Account.java and Object.java
The "where method override" in Account.java tries to dereference Object class from Object.java, as it is in the same directory. And is not dereferencing from java.lang.Object

Java & compiler details;
% mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.9.8 (36645f6c9b5079805ea5009217e36f2cffd34256)
Maven home: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.9.8/libexec
Java version: 21.0.4, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "14.6", arch: "aarch64", family: "mac"

I see, so the root cause of this problem isn't related to java.lang.Object, but to your runtime library being outdated, see my updated answer.

Here are some workarounds:
Specify which types to always fully qualify
There's a configuration flag that allows for specifying which types should always be fully qualified in jOOQ's code generation output:
<configuration>
  <generator>
    <generate>
      <fullyQualifiedTypes>java\.lang\.Object</fullyQualifiedTypes>
    </generate>
  </generator>
</configuration>

That would be the simplest solution here.
Using a generator strategy to rename the org.jooqtest.Object
Programmatic or configurative generator strategies can help you rename the generated Object class to Object_ or whatever, e.g. when using the configurative approach:
<configuration>
  <generator>
    <strategy>
      <matchers>
        <tables>
          <table>
            <expression>OBJECT</expression>
            <pojoClass>
              <expression>$0_</expression>
              <transform>PASCAL</transform>
            </pojoClass>
          </table>
        </tables>
      </matchers>
    </strategy>
  </generator>
</configuration>

Turn off that particular code generation feature
You can turn off the generation of these where() method overrides:
<configuration>
  <generator>
    <generate>
      <whereMethodOverrides>false</whereMethodOverrides>
    </generate>
  </generator>
</configuration>


Thank you @lukas. I am able to continue by disabling whereMethodOverrides. I do not want to rename the table or generated code, so this method helps for now.

FYI, Both code generator and runtime libraries are using the same jooq version. For reference I am sharing git repo here: https://github.com/spsheni/jooqtest

@ShyamaPraveena: Ah, I get it now, thanks for the reproducer. I wonder if this is a bug. We have a utility that helps work around this problem: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-generate/codegen-generate-fully-qualified-types. You could specify that you always want java.lang.Object references to be fully qualified in your generated code. Though, it would be nice if this worked out of the box, of course.

FYI, It appears there is a typo above and in jooq documentation, whereMethodOverrides works when is under generate ( not when under database ).
